# How to use Rnw and bib files in Lyx?

Tags: lyx

I am writing for publication in Transportation Research Board. Someone un-officially created a LaTeX template for the journal ([here](http://ite.ce.gatech.edu/?p=681)). The template consists of 3 files with these extensions:

1. .bib
2. .rnw
3. .bst

How can I get started with using these files in Lyx?

Comment: Please post a MWE such that users have a starting point

Comment: You have two recent questions that have answers that you have not responded to. Please accept them or give feedback on what's wrong with them before posting new questions (I don't think there's a rule against this, it's just my personal opinion). otherwise people might continue to search for questions that do not have accepted answers and spend their time figuring out how to solve them. And yes, please post a MWE. See, for example here: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 1):

I just came accross a similar problem but I am using Texmaker. Yet you might find a way to transfer it to another software. After several trials, here is what I came with:

1. Install R
2. In your editor, you should be able to customize the build options. Add this command:

   ```
   "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/bin/x64/R.exe" CMD Sweave %.Rnw
   ```

   (if you are with a 64x, check the version of R as the directory changes with it)

   ```
   "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/bin/R.exe" CMD Sweave %.Rnw
   ```

   esle.
3. Run the command, it will output a .tex file
4. Use your .tex file as usual. You might get an error like `Sweave.sty not found`.
5. To remove this error you need to add the path:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\share\texmf"
   ```

   to your LaTeX distribution. If MikTeX, open settings as `admin > root > add`.

However, I can't get the wordcount working for now.

Cheers,

Comment: I'm not actually sure how helpful this is, the OP uses LyX which isn't a text editor.